# Return new type of me? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, types, constructor, return

I would like to do something like any of these, that atchually works though,
so i can just put it in my base class and be done with it?

```
    returnVal = new TypeOf(Me)
    returnVal = new Me.GetType()
    returnVal = new Me
    returnVal = new TypeOf(Me)
    returnVal = Me.new()
    returnVal = New class(Of me)
    returnVal = New me.class
    returnVal = me.class.new()
    returnVal = new typeof me.class
```

Comment: You didn't try all possible permutations, it is `returnVal = Me.GetType()`  You can't write vb.net code if you don't understand the `New` keyword.  Not understanding the `Overridable` or `Implements` keyword is common enough but that's what you really should use.

Comment: So, you want to create a new instance of the same type as the current instance?  None of what you have there makes any sense in that context because if you're going to use the `New` keyword to invoke a constructor then you have to specify a a data type explicitly.  An instance of the `Type` class is not a data type.  It's an object that represents a data type.

Comment: The question is, why would you want to write code like that anyway?  Is it in a base class and you want derived classes to be able to use it too?  If not then you have written the code for the current class so why not specify the type explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

I did it

```
Class ClassToClone
    Implements ICloneable

    Public Overridable Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        Return CloneVal({})
    End Function

    Public Function CloneVal(args() as Object) As Object
        Dim t As Type = MyClass.GetType()

        Dim constr As Reflection.ConstructorInfo = t.GetConstructor(New Type() {})

        Dim result As Object = constr.Invoke(args)

        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```